# Search for IDs from text file with python + selenium + webdriver and write to url to file

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

What I am trying to do 
open a url,
read a text file take product id from file one by one,
enter that into input field called search on webpage,
click on search button,
find out all available vendors links on page,
open all vendors links in new tabs,
write those urls into file.

What I tried:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=d:\\abprofile")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://xxxxxx/products")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']")
main_window = driver.current_window_handle
with open('d:/ids.txt') as in_file:
    for ids in in_file:
        elem.send_keys(ids)
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id,'search')]").click()
addr = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//a[contains(.,'Available Vendors')])"))
for addrNum in range(addr):

    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(.,'Available Vendors')])[" + str(addrNum + 1) + "]")
    href = ele.get_attribute('href')

    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + href + "');")
    time.sleep(4)
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    if handle != main_window:
        print(handle)
        page = handle
        driver.switch_to.window(page)
        time.sleep(7)
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Verfiy quotes')]").click()
        print(driver.current_url)
        urls = driver.current_url
        print (urls)
        with open('d:/somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(urls+"\n")
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

But its failing when i submit ids from file saying

```
 no such element: Unable to locate element: 
 {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@id,'search')]"}
```

But when i hardcode only one product id like below, then its working

working:

`elem.send_keys("34564545666")`

Not working:

`with open('d:/ids.txt') as in_file:
    for ids in in_file:
        elem.send_keys(ids)
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id,'search')]").click()`

any suggestion , what wrong thing...

Comment: Do you need a wait for presence of element located by in there? For the element you are attempting to click?

Comment: I believe it's not failing at the first iteration, but in second. Right?

Comment: yes, second iteration its failing

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause: This is cause of the following line in your first for loop.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id,'search')]").click()
```

Here you are overwriting the elem with button, and trying to sendkeys. Change the above line to 'driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id,'search')]").click()`

Also you can do the below.

```
# assign elem in the first for loop
for ids in in_file:
    editElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']")
    editElem.send_keys(ids)
```

Comment: Hello @supputuri sir, the above methods not working..what happening is its inputting first id from file, clicking on search button,-- available vendors listed..-- then terminating with erros unable to locate search...i am not sure why its searching for search button on available vendors page.it wont be there on result of available ..it seems i am missing some identation for loops , not sure where it is.. huh, however single works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file using the open(), it has the \n character(New line character)at the end.

```
with open('d:/ids.txt') as in_file:
    for ids in in_file:
        elem.send_keys(ids)
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id,'search')]").click()
```

print(ids) will print : "34564545666\n",
not "34564545666"

You must use a String without \n character as a parameter.

So you can use ids.rstrip() (deletes the space at the right end.)
 or ids[:-1] (without last character. (\n))